# Prevent layout below max height and width size

Tags: android, button, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, scrollviewer

I've got a simple layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:id="@+id/ddd"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 tools:context=".pkgTestforend.DriverListFragment">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:liftOnScroll="true" >

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:id="@+id/topAppBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:title="PageTitle"
                app:menu="@menu/top_app_bar"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:navigationIcon="@drawable/baseline_menu_24"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
                />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


            <com.example.dochjavatestimplementation.pkgTestforend.CustomLinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/cusLL"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <ListView
                                android:id="@+id/listAllDrivers"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                            <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                                android:id="@+id/btnOpenDriverAddFragment2"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/baseline_person_add_24"
                                app:elevation="0dp" />

                    </RelativeLayout>

            </com.example.dochjavatestimplementation.pkgTestforend.CustomLinearLayout>


    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Which looks like this:

[image: example]

As can be seen the issue is that the button is below the phone height size in case that the listview is very large, how can the height be set to so that is always at the bottom right and not below the height?
Is it due to the scrollingview which causes the floating button be shown always below?

Comment: Use constraints layout

Comment: Also, you have your FloatingActionButton inside a custom layout inside a scroll view, what did you expected?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this layout resource file code and use constraint layout too, the float button should be in the constraint layout and move it to the end bottom of the layout, then add your Coordinator Layout and inside it add your Nested Scroll View, then add in it your custom linear layout containing your app bar layout with replacing the list view to recycler view into it, you have to enable set nested scrolling enabled to true in your recycler view to enable scrolling on items.

[image]
[image]

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/ddd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:liftOnScroll="true">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:id="@+id/topAppBar"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:menu="@menu/top_app_bar"
                app:navigationIcon="@drawable/baseline_menu_24"
                app:title="PageTitle" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/listAllDrivers"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                tools:itemCount="50" />
        </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>`
```